# Access denied for user anonymous while accessing custom table data

Tags: 7, services

I am trying to fetch custom table result anonymously with services but I am getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Access denied for user anonymous

My Code are as follow :

```
    function custom_data_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'getdata' => array(
      'retrieve' => array(
        'help' => 'Retrieves a data',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'custom_data'),
        'callback' => '_get_data',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the note to get',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'index' => array(
        'help' => 'Retrieves a listing of notes',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'custom_data'),
        'callback' => '_get_data',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'page',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => '',
            'source' => array(
              'param' => 'page',
            ),
            'optional' => TRUE,
            'default value' => 0,
          ),
          array(
            'name' => 'parameters',
            'type' => 'array',
            'description' => '',
            'source' => 'param',
            'optional' => TRUE,
            'default value' => array(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I tried with "X-CSRF-Token" also But no luck :(

Any help appreciated

Comment: I'd recommend using the `actions` variable in your array as described here: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Services/Create_a_Custom_Service - The CRUDI approach you are using is typically reserved for custom Entity Types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up with an answer from our comments...

Here's an example custom service resource:

**custom_data.module**

```
function custom_data_services_resources() {
  $resources = array(
    'custom_data_resources' => array(
      'actions' => array(
        'getdata' => array(
          'help' => t('Gets custom data.'),
          'file' => array(
            'type' => 'inc',
            'module' => 'custom_data',
            'name' => 'custom_data.resource',
          ),
          'callback' => 'custom_data_getdata',
          'args' => array(
            array(
              'name' => 'data',
              'type' => 'array',
              'description' => 'The data dude.',
              'source' => 'data',
              'optional' => FALSE,
            )
          ),
          'access callback' => 'custom_data_access',
          'access callback file' => array(
            'type' => 'inc',
            'module' => 'custom_data',
            'name' => 'custom_data.resource',
          ),
          'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
          'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $resources;
}
```

**custom_data.resource.inc**

```
function custom_data_getdata($data) {
  return array('foo' => $data['bar']);
}

function custom_data_access($permission) {
  return user_access($permission);
}
```

After that, just enable the custom resource under your endpoint's configuration and clear all of Drupal's caches. Then you can make a **POST** to:

`?q=[my-endpoint]/custom_data_resources/getdata.json`

If you need to send along custom arguments, I usually recommend a single `array` parameter, that way you can easily expand upon it and send as many variables/properties you need along with the payload:

`{ "bar": 123 }`

Which will then return to you:

`{ "foo": 123 }`

Don't forget to attach a header to your request with a name of `X-CSRF-Token` and value retrieved from: `?q=services/session/token`